# Please help me understand this basic C++ class implementation

Tags: c++

For an assigment, I must implement a C++ constructor taking as parameter an array of objects of another class. I'm having trouble understanding the following :

a.h :

```
class a {
public :
  a(const b &bb);
private :
  b bb_[10];
};
```

a.cc :

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
a::a(const b &bb) {
  *bb_ = bb;
}
```

It seems to work, but what's going on there? The goal would be to initialize bb_ as an array of 10 objects of class b. b class has a default constructor.

Thanks !

Comment: which specific part isn't clear? in order to answer the question we have to know which part you don't understand.

Comment: What you´re doing here: Passing a single object of b a parameter (reference), then assigning a copy ob this object to bb_[0] (unless b has a non-copying copy constructor). The other 9 places in the array remain unused.

Comment: There is no initialisation here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is discussion-oriented rather than a concrete question about some technique or feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above does compile, but I'm not sure if the logic is correct.

You see, the line `*bb_ = bb;` **only** fills the first element of the array. When you dereference a pointer to an array, you get its first element (at index 0).

What you want to do is to fill up the whole array, not just the first element:

```
const int SIZE = 10;   // please use constants for array sizes

class a {
public :
  a(const b (&bb)[SIZE]) ;
private :
  b bb_[SIZE];
};

a::a(const b (&bb) [SIZE]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      bb_[i] = bb[i];
}
```

---

If you don't like the loop in the constructor, you can use `memcpy()` function that will literally copy bytes of memory from `bb` into your array:

```
a::a(b (&bb) [SIZE]) {
  memcpy(bb, bb_, sizeof(bb));
}
```

---

Another way is to use a safer alternative: `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

const int SIZE = 10;

class a {
public :
  a(std::array<b, SIZE> bb);
private :
  std::array<b, SIZE> bb_;
};

a::a(std::array<b, SIZE> bb) {
  bb_ = bb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression I could just change the "address" of the internal array bb_ to the one of bb's (the argument).

Comment: @user3020233 By dereferencing (using a `*`), you don't get access to an address. You get the opposite, you get direct access to an element from its reference. `bb_` is a pointer to an array, `*bb_` is the first element of the array that `bb_` points to.

Comment: If bb_ is a pointer to an array, wouldn't it be possible to change it so it points to the array bb then? I've tried everything but can't figure out how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: @user3020233 It's not very safe to do that. What if the `bb` array is edited or removed later? `bb_` will be left in an invalid state... I will edit my answer to show you a couple more alternatives

Answer (score 0):

`*bb_` is simply `bb_[0]` so the constructor of `a` is just copying the specified `b` to the first cell of its internal array of 10 `b`.

If you want to copy `bb` in all the 10 cells of the internal array `bb_`, do this:

```
std::fill(bb_, bb_ + 10, bb);
```

If you want to copy an array of 10 `b` to the internal array `bb_`, you need to declare the parameter `bb` as such an array in the constructor:

```
a::a(b bb[10]) {
  std::copy(bb, bb + 10, bb_);
}
```

Finally, if you want to copy the address of an array of 10 `b` to `a`, then `bb_` should simply be declared as a pointer and the parameter `bb` specified in the constructor should be changed as well to be a pointer:

a.h :

```
class a {
public :
  a(const b* bb);
private :
  const b* bb_;
};
```

a.cc :

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
a::a(const b* bb) {
  bb_ = bb;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. I'm trying to make the internal array bb_ point to the array passed in the arguments list (bb). Isn't there a way to change bb_'s address to bb's without copying all array elements?

Comment: Then `bb_` should be a pointer not an array.